# Nested User controls - return Form on which placed

Tags: vb6, nested

First time posting.
Doing work in VB6

I have a Form (frmMC) on which are placed nested user controls.

```
frmMC
.... xMcNew [User Control]
     .......xPage [User Control]
 .................cmdPageDown1 [Control]
```

Using these statements inserted in the  cmdPageDown1 code block:

```
Debug.Print Screen.ActiveControl.Name
Debug.Print UserControl.Name
Debug.Print ActiveControl.Name
```

I can return the name values of 3 of the 4 that I want. Namely,

xMCGridNew1
xPage
cmdPageDown1

How do I return the name of the parent (frmMC)?

```
Debug.Print [Magic Incantation Statements]
Debug.Print Screen.ActiveControl.Name
Debug.Print UserControl.Name
Debug.Print ActiveControl.Name
```

What is the Magic Incantation Statement(s)?

I do have a variable

```
g_strPredecessorForm = Me.Name
```

that is currently used on the load event of the form, and it is visible/exposed to the user controls by virtue of its global nature, and this is used to get that name, but I was thinking there is a more direct way.

Thanks.

Comment: `What is the Magic Incantation` Software development is not Black Magic, it is largely a result of much research and reading - especially the info at your fingertips.  After you read [ask] and take the [tour] (`first time posting`, dont you know), examine the list of options that the IDE gives you when you type the dot in `cmdPageDown1.` or any other control.  Which one of those might be the form?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Parent.Name`

Comment: At the line Debug.Print Parent.Name error thrown that Object does not support that property. (Also there is no Container property of the Control with this parent - child - grandchild - greatgrandchild relationship shown below.)

frmMC
.... xMcNew [User Control]
     .......xPage [User Control]
 .................cmdPageDown1 [Control]

Answer (score 0):

When you start working with custom controls, the properties can get a bit confusing. As I understand your question, you have a UserControl called `xPage`, which contains a constituent CommandButton control called `cmdPageDown1`. Then, you have another UserControl called `xMcNew`, which contains an instance of your `xPage` control. This answer assumes my understanding to be correct.

The `Parent` property doesn't work consistently with nested custom controls. (The reason it didn't work for you, though, is because you have to use the form `myControlName.Parent.Name`, and you didn't reference any control. The error that you were getting is basically asking "Whose parent?")

Also, using `Screen.ActiveControl.Name`is a bit roundabout and inconsistent: if it works in your case that's coincidental, and if you make changes in your structure you're likely to find that it stops working. A better solution is to use the `ParentControls` collection of the `UserControl` object.

The `ParentControls` collection contains references to all the controls in the parent object's `Controls` collection.The first member of the collection is always the container of the control (as far as I know, you might want to test that more thoroughly than I have). Have a look at this code:

```
Dim i As Integer
With UserControl
    For i = 0 To .ParentControls.Count - 1
        Debug.Print .ParentControls(i).Name
    Next
End With
```

If you run this from command buttons on various levels of your nested controls, you'll begin to see how `ParentControls` works. The references you're looking for work out to these (from `cmdPageDown1`'s `Click` event handler):

```
Debug.Print ActiveControl.Name                          'cmdPageDown1
Debug.Print UserControl.Name                            'xPage
Debug.Print UserControl.ParentControls(0).Name          'xMCGridNew1
Debug.print UserControl.ParentControls(0).Parent.Name   'frmMC
```

Now, keep in mind that if you go one level deeper with nesting, you can't do it this way. The references to the controls in the `ParentControls` collection don't themselves include a `UserControl` object in their interface. So, if you try this, you'll get an error:

```
Debug.print UserControl.ParentControls(0).UserControl.ParentControls(0).Name
```

I know because I tried it. :) If you want to go another level of nesting, you'll have to come up with something like a custom property that returns a complete instance of the parent control if it's a user control, and something else if it isn't.

Comment: Great info... our legacy program ia in vb 6 and we have thought about refactoring.. maybe to dot .Net ... Does dot.Net have a better capability to handle such things as returning the names of nested controls? I find such name returning very helpful in debugging and also is other tasks)  such as writing things to event logs. ( such as capturing this nested informatin as to what "button" users clicked.

Comment: @billjenkins Probably, but I'm not an expert in .Net custom controls. I used to teach the VB6 classes back in the day, so I know this subject very well, but I didn't do the same with .Net for various reasons.